# How to test that a form successfully submitted using Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm writing feature specs for my Article form.

In one test, I have RSpec look for certain form inputs using the labels:

```
expect(find_field("Title")).to_not be_nil
```

Now I'd like to know if the form was submitted properly.  How can I do this using RSpec, **if you aren't supposed to check the database** from a feature spec?

For example, what if I mistyped the `name` attribute on the `Title` input?  The label would still be found by my `find_field()` call, and controller specs would have me specify the `title` in a hash.

Answer (score 0):

In this case one would assume a Title would be required for an Article so if the name attribute was misspelled the creation of the Article would fail and you'd end up on an error page (Also an unpermitted parameter would raise in the creation by default in test mode with strong parameters).  If its a field not required for creation of the Article then the assumption is that the info is displayed in the app somewhere and can be checked for on that page.

As an aside your sample expect would read much clearer if rewritten as

```
expect(page).to have_field('Title')
```

Answer (score 0):

There are loads of way to approach this:

```
expect(page).to have_field('Title')

expect(page).to have_css('#someSelector')

expect(current_path).to eq article_path (for example)

expect(page).to have_content "ABC" (i.e. some content which will be rendered)
```

The Capybara readme on Github is a really good one full of easy to follow examples - https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara.

Comment: Thanks, but only the last one is really useful here... I know it has a field "Title" since I'm filling it in, and looking for a selector doesn't really help.  The path might be correct, but I'm not wondering if it got submitted at all, but whether the title that was entered was saved (assuming it's not required). I guess my problem with the last one is is that it can get tricky if the data is not all rendered on one page!